# Fastest sorted string concatenation

Tags: python

What is the fastest and most efficient way to do this:

```
word = "dinosaur"

newWord = word[0] + ''.join(sorted(word[1:]))
```

output:

```
"dainorsu"
```

Thoughts:

Would something as converting the word to an array increase performance? I read somewhere that arrays have less overhead due to them being the same data type compared to a string.

Basically I want to sort everything after the first character in the string as fast as possible. If memory is saved that would also be a plus. The problem I am trying to solve needs to be within a certain time limit so I am trying to be as fast as possible. I dont know much about python efficiency under the hood so if you explain why this method is fast as well that would be AWESOME!

Comment: why is sorting a 8-letter word an efficiency concern?

Comment: @Pavel its for the purposes of meeting the time limit, as Liondancer pointed out.

Comment: @Pavel well the problem I am trying to solve needs to be under 500ms. Maybe I am going overboard but I want to be safe. here is the problem if you're interested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025362/word-ranking-efficiency

Comment: @Liondancer Why don't you try C or at least Cython?

Comment: though I understand, I'm really not sure if this is the right question if the problem is an algorithmic one. I'll buy it if you say that you already have a prototype doing the right thing but taking 575 ms even for long words :) micro-optimization leads you to unreadable code (which is non-pythonic) and, in the end, to C/C++ :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd approach it.

Create an array of size 26 (assuming that only lowercase letters are used).  Then iterate through each character in the string.  For the 1st letter of the alphabet, increment the 1st index of the array; for the 2nd, increment the 2nd.  Once you've scanned the whole string (which is of complexity O(n)) you will be able to reconstruct it afterwards by repeating the 'a' array[0] times, 'b' array[1] times, and so on.

This approach would beat a fast sort algorithm like quicksort or partition sort, which have complexity O(nlogn).

EDIT: Finally you'd also want to reassemble the final string efficiently.  The string concatenation provided by some languages using the + operator can be inefficient, so consider using an efficient string builder class.